# return each string representation in a list of user-defined objects in a new line

Tags: python, oop

I have a list where each element is a user-defined class, `class_object_list`. I wish to return each string representation of that list in a new line and the code needs to be wrapped inside an f-string (or would work inside a return statement).

Or basically, put the equivalent of the following code inside a return statment

```
for i in class_object_list:
    print(i)
```

i've tried `''.join([str(i) for i in class_object_list])` but it doesnt print each string representation in a new line.

Also tried `nl = '\n'`, `f"{nl.join([*class_object_list])}"` but it gave a `TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance` error.

And tried `print(*class_object_list, sep='\n')` but it only works with a print statement

Comment: All you need is `'\n'.join([str(i) for i in class_object_list])`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use:

```
'\n'.join([str(i) for i in class_object_list])
```

Or:

```
'\n'.join(map(str, class_object_list))
```

Comment: I know lists can be faster with `str.join`, but somehow it always bugs me to see comprehensions where generator expressions suffice :D

Comment: @schwobaseggl haha yeah! Raymond mentioned that in one of his posts, it's ruining everything :P